# Alternative to nested ternary operator?

Tags: javascript, reactjs, operators

```
{isPage ? (
      hasHtml? (
        <iframe
          src="about:blank"
          title="pages"
          frameBorder="0"
          scrolling="no"
        />
      ) : (
        <p>This page has no html</p>
      )
    ) : (
      <iframe
        src="about:blank"
        title="pages"
        frameBorder="0"
        scrolling="no"
      />
    )}
```

This code block has nested ternary operator ? Is there any alternatives for this so that i dont have to repeat the iframe code block portion twice ? That portion seems redundant. Thanks

Comment: `(isPage && !hasHtml) ? <p>...</p> : <iframe ... />`?

Comment: You can create a new component for iframe code. Components are independent and reusable bits of code.

Answer (score 0):

As suggested in one of the comments:

```
   {isPage && !hasHtml? (
      <p>This page has no html</p>
    ) : (
      <iframe
        src="about:blank"
        title="pages"
        frameBorder="0"
        scrolling="no"
      />
    )}
```